# How to run UIAutomation on simulator using Xcode bots

Tags: xcode6, osx-server, xcode-bots

I am using Xcode 6.3.1 and OS X server 4
i have a template for UI automation and i would like the test success failure to be logged in the bot.

is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The right answer would be that no, there is no way to get the results from Instruments after the UI Automation runs and display the results with the unit tests bot results.

But...

If you really want to hack some stuff together you really could make it work by using the info given [HERE](https://github.com/czechboy0/Buildasaur#xcode-server-reverse-engineering) and then parsing the results and modifying the Xcode NodeJS server that displays the data to also display the UI Automation results.

OPINION:

I would say the second option is not worth the time and effort and that it would be better to use a framework like [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF) which runs UI tests like unit tests so you can get the results in Xcode Bot.